# How to get names of background running apps in android?

Tags: android

For example, I have "music" and " speech recorder" run in my AVD background. I want to make a AlertDialog that can show the names " music, speech recorder".  Who can give me some codes? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may help you...

```
public static HashSet<String> getRunningApps(Context context) {
    final HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>();
    final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    List<RunningTaskInfo> runningTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    for (RunningTaskInfo runningTaskInfo : runningTasks) {
        String packageName = runningTaskInfo.baseActivity.getPackageName();
        try {
            String appName = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0).loadLabel(packageManager).toString();
            hashSet.add(appName);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException exception) {
            // handle Exception
        }
    }
    return hashSet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can list all processes with the followings lines:

```
ActivityManager localActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

List RunningServiceInfo services = localActivityManager .getRunningServices(100);
```

And from [RunningServiceInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo.html) you can get details for the process. 
Another way is using [getRunningAppProcesses](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses%28%29).